# How do I combine these three MySQL data queries into one query with multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these three queries, that I need to combine into one.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(datamb) AS value_sum FROM maindata GROUP BY phonenumber";



$sql1 = "select dataplan as currentplan from maindata GROUP BY phonenumber";



$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT phonenumber AS value_sum1 FROM maindata";
```

So I can display them in three columns like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo "<TABLE id='display'>";
echo "<td><b>Data Usage This Period: ". ROUND ($row["value_sum"],2) . "MB</b></td> ";
echo "<td><b>Data Plan: ". $row["currentplan"] . "</b></td> "; 
echo "<td><b>Phone Number: ". $row["phonenumber"] . "</b></td> ";  
echo "</TABLE>"; 

}
```

I have used UNION which just makes one big column with all the data correct which is close, but I need them to all display in one table in three columns.  Thank you for any thoughts, if you thought is I should punch myself in the face, already done :)

Comment: `select dataplan, phonenumber, sum(datamb) as sum_datamb from maindata group by dataplan, phonenumber order by dataplan, phonenumber` ....?

Comment: illegal group by in $sql1 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: Can you describe the problem and mention what you want to achieve? and give table details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the `GROUP BY` keyword to create distinct records and sum over the remaining values.**

```
SELECT   phonenumber,
         dataplan AS currentplan,
         SUM(datamb) AS value_sum
FROM     maindata
GROUP BY phonenumber, dataplan;
```

This query will give you unique combinations of phone number and data plan, and will sum the `datamb` field within these distinct groups.  This is great practice for learning the `GROUP BY` keyword which is very useful for this kind of calculation.

**EDIT:** When you see a `DISTINCT`, that's one hint that you can also `GROUP BY` that field.  It means there are likely duplicate values in that column or group of columns.  Make sure there's a key defined for this specific group of fields with the same order as the `ORDER BY` clause for maximum efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

illegal group by in $sql1

please inform yourself on the use of group by.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

query would be
with illegal grouping:

```
select 
SUM(datamb) AS value_sum, 
dataplan as "first plan row value in this table for this phone number",
phonenumber AS value_sum1 
FROM maindata 
group by phonenumber
```

or without:

```
select 
SUM(datamb) AS value_sum, 
dataplan as currentplan ,
phonenumber AS value_sum1 
FROM maindata 
group by phonenumber, dataplan
```